# Is a Foreach loop a type of block?

Tags: closures

In thinking about blocks, I've always wondered why the

`thingers.each { |thing|`

example is actually interesting (since there's another, built-in way to do it). In most modern languages there's a way to iterate through a collection and apply some inline code to it. But then I thought that maybe the `for (Thing thing : things) {` syntax is really a type of block, even in languages like Java-sans-Groovy where there are none.

So the question is: Is a for-each loop a type of block, albeit with a fixed syntax?

**Edit:** This question is confusing but yet got some attention so I can't delete it. Anyway... by Blocks I mean "closures" and not just code blocks. As far as why I tagged this as language agnostic is that I'm not interested in how a for-each is implemented under-the-hood. I'm more interested in whether, from a programmer's perspective, a for-each could be considered a freebie closure in languages that doesn't have them, like Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most definitely not language agnostic (as it is tagged).

For example, in Ruby, you are passing a closure or block to the .each method.  The semantics are defined by the language.

In C#, foreach compiles to a call to IEnumerable.GetEnumerator and the use of the IEnumerator.MoveNext method.  It just depends on the language.

EDIT:

> Edit: This question is confusing but yet got some attention so I can't delete it. Anyway... by Blocks I mean "closures" and not just code blocks. As far as why I tagged this as language agnostic is that I'm not interested in how a for-each is implemented under-the-hood. I'm more interested in whether, from a programmer's perspective, a for-each could be considered a freebie closure in languages that doesn't have them, like Java.

No, you are thinking only of one use case for a closure. You can't pass a control structure to a method as you can a closure in some languages. A control structure is not a first class first class data type like a closure is in some languages. In the case of "run this code on each object in a collection" yes, they are semantically similar. However, that it only one example of what you can do with a closure.

You say that you w

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for your answer. You have 13K so you can change the tags or the question as you see fit. Had you not answered it, and gotten upvoted, I could've deleted it, which is no longer possible. I am not really asking how the thing gets implemented. I'm asking if, from a programmer's perspective, control structures and closures are ever essentially identical.

Comment: I like this, "You can't pass a control structure to a method as you can a closure in some languages." I didn't think of that: that's part of the joy of closures is that they can be assigned to variables and passed about.

Answer (score 1):

As Swangren says, this question is not language agnostic as tagged. Not unless there's some general "IT theory" definition of a "block" that I'm not aware of.

In Java, a "block" is a series of statements enclosed in { }. So a FOR statement normally operates on a block. The purpose of a block is to delimit what is included within certain language constructs, like IF statements and loops.

I believe C and C++ have similar definitions of a "block".

Most languages have a similar concept.

Not sure if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate. My definition of a "block" is a section of code that's grouped together. In this case there's a lot of stuff in Java can be a "block"

If you are talking about ruby-style blocks, which are really closures, then Java doesn't support them (not in any sane fashion anyways). `foreach` is a control structure, and behaves differently from closures.

On your updated question: It's easy to use closures as control structures, but the other way around is harder, if not impossible. A closure is a first class function, which allows you to do some pretty cool stuff with it - not just iterating through elements.

Comment: Hmmm... that was my definition of block too, but now I mean blocks as in "blocks coming soon to Objetive-C (closures)" or "Ruby blocks are cool" (closures). I think I mean closures.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($foo as $bar) {
    $baz = 'Hello, World!';
}

echo $baz; // 'Hello, World!', "leaked" from the "closure"
```

Nope, sorry, `foreach` loops are not lambdas, closures or functions in languages where they aren't explicitly such.

Comment: PHP is a mess. That does not happen in C++ or Java.

Comment: @quantum It does not happen in languages that have *block scopes*. That doesn't make languages that have function or object scopes messy, it just makes them different. *(That's not to say that PHP isn't a mess, just not for this reason. ;))*